# Proving $x=f^n(x)$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Let $A$ be a nonempty set and let $f:A \rightarrow A$ be a bijective function. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f^n$ be a function $A \rightarrow A$ given by

$$f^n = f \circ \cdots \circ f$$

where the $f$ occurs $n$ times in the nested composition. The given definition can then be extended $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We define $f^0 = i_A$. Because $f$ is bijective, $f^n$ is bijective.

I am asked to prove that if $x \in A$, then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=f^n(x)$. Since $n$ is existential, I see no issue with just setting $n=0$ after being given an arbitrary $x \in A$, so that $f^0(x) = i_A(x) = x$, satisfying the proof.

However, I can't help but feel that this is too easy. Is there a better way to prove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean $n \to \mathbb{Z}$? From what you said the problem assumes $n$ is a natural number, why are you extending it to the integers?

Comment: Fixed the $\rightarrow$, and the problem is extending it to $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Is $A$ assumed to be countable?

Comment: I should also note that the problem defines the inverse of $f$ to be $f^{-n} = (f^n)^{-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Can you please write out the problem *exactly* as it is written where you obtained it from?

Comment: No assumption is made on whether $A$ is countable or uncountable, just that it is not empty, although this section precedes a discussion set cardinality concerning infinite sets.

Comment: I think we must require $n> 0$, or else the problem is trivial.  But then the statement is not always true if $A$ is not finite, as Jendrik points out.  So I would check the exact wording of the question.  So I would say there was a mistake in the original question, or else you have communicated it incorrectly here.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider the bijection $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x+1$, then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the only possible choice is $n = 0$, because $f^n(x) = x+n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

PS: A more interesting result is that in the case of $A$ being finite there exists $n > 0$ such that $f^n(x) = x$ for every $x \in A$, i.e. $n > 0$ can be choosen independently of $x$. This follows because $f$ is an element of the symmetric group on $A$, which has finite order.